# Powershell: Start-Job returns a "How do you want to open this file" with some cmdlets

Tags: powershell

Im just getting started with Powershell and im starting to get the hang of it.
Im currently working on a script where i would like to run different things in parallel. For example i would like to capture some performance statistics in the background while some other things are running. So i found this great cmdlet called Start-Job that would do exactly what i want to do. So i created a small script with a Get-Counter to gather performance data. The command run fine on its own. But when i try to run it as a Job i get a popup with a "How do you want to open this file". If i choose notepad, i get nothing it it and the job runs without any data.

It looks like it happends everytime i try to run Get-Counter insdie the scriptblock statement. Other things work for some reason.
Any help would be appritiated.

Example. This Works:

```
start-job -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem}
```

This does not work

```
start-job -ScriptBlock {Get-Counter}
```

Im guessing there are some kind of permissions i need or or is there something about Start-Job that i dont understand?

Comment: Please provide more detail on your Get-Counter command. This works just fine. `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time'}`

Comment: As i stated above. It doesnt even work when i run Get-Counter as a job.
If i run youtr command i ghet the same issue. I get a popup asking me to select a program to open something.

Answer (score 1):

Haha well im a bit embarrassed to say this but i found the solution by myself.
So if anyone else is having issues with getting the "How do you want to open this file?"-message.
It turned out that i had accidently created an empty file in C:\Windows\System32 called "Get-Counter" (with no file extension). So every time i tried to run the "Get-Counter" command, it tried to open my empty file...
I just removed the file and everything started working again.